# regex to match first instance of a word but only when preceeded by match from another pattern

Tags: regex, postgresql, posix

I've found some info on finding the first instance of a word in a string, but I'm trying to find the first instance of a word (two, actually, but in separate calls) only when it is preceded by some very specific text (an IP address delimited by underscores) that varies slightly. Also, these words are separated by underscores, so for some reason `\b` isn't working for me.

Here's some example strings to test against *one line at a time*. Only bolded words should be matched.

- 192_168_10_2_**card**02_port01_other_text_with_card_or_port
- 10_22_1_200_**card**4_port5_another_string_with_port_or_card
- something_else_with_card_or_port_in_it

And in a second call, I'd like to match a different word in these strings.

- 192_168_10_2_card02_**port**01_other_text_with_card_or_port
- 10_22_1_200_card4_**port**5_another_string_with_port_or_card
- something_else_with_card_or_port_in_it

My regex flavor is POSIX regex (for PostgreSQL 9.4).  I've been able to run with anything that works in here http://regexpal.com/ so far.

Even if it can't solve for all 3 examples at once, if it could just solve for the first two, that would be very helpful.

Edit:  To be absolutely clear, my intent is to replace the first string 'card' with the character 'c' and then to replace the first string 'port' with the letter 'p' without affecting any instance of 'card' or 'port' that are not immediately followed by numbers.  This is why my match needs to include just those first words without their corresponding numbers.

Comment: do you know that the input will always have card[numbers]_port?

Comment: Hmm, I just realized you might want to match a string with card and no port, a string with port and no card, and a string with card followed by port.  Can you be more specific as to exactly which string configurations you should match?  For example, is it okay to have a string with port then card, or does it have to be card then port?  Can the string have only one or the other, so a string with port but not card?

Comment: Yes, there will always be numbers (1 or 2 digits) immediately following the 'card' or 'port' word I want to match, and they should always occur in that order.  Whatever comes after should be irrelevant, as long as it doesn't end up with a repeating match of 'card' or 'port'.

Comment: You forgot to *specify* the `very specific text` you mention ...

Comment: The very specific text is just an ip address separated by underscores in lieu of periods, as shown in the example.  Try not to overthink the details and permutations... I'm sure if someone can solve for the 3 examples posted above, I can figure out how to make it fit what I have.  Only the bolded text should return a match.  The only reason I didn't ask for just one of these words was because I wasn't sure if it changed the answer if the matched word immediately followed the necessary IP string or not.

Comment: Can you use http://www.regexr.com? regexpal.com is NOT showing capture groups...

Comment: I'm getting the same exact results on regexr.com as regexpal.com

Comment: If you hold your mouse over the highlight it will shown the different match groups in regexr.com. Try it.

Comment: Group 1 was the IP.  Group 2 was 'card02' and group 3 was 'port01'.  What can I do with that info?

Comment: To whoever downvoted: regex is not easy to learn!  I'd appreciate some constructive criticism, or else you're not really helping anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use negative lookahead you can use `card((?!port).)*port` to match a string with card, than any number of characters not followed by port, then card again.

EDIT:

if the input is always in the same format, then you can be more specific by using `card[0-9]{1,2}_port`.  This will keep it from matching any other extraneous instances of card and port

EDIT2:

to match only the word in the first case you can use a positive lookahead: `card(?=[0-9]{1,2}_port)`.  Im not sure if your flavor allows positive lookbehind (the tester doesnt, but that is in js), but give `(?<=card[0-9]{1,2}_)port` a shot.  If positive lookbehind doesnt work you may need to look into alternatives.

Comment: I tested this, and it just matched everything in between and including 'card' and 'port' for all instances.  I only need to match the first instance of one of those words (at a time), and it should be regardless of whether or not the word gets repeated.

Comment: are you looking to match only the words card and port and only in that order?  If you can answer my question in the comment above I can be more specific.

Comment: I think I answered it.  If it's confusing you, you can probably just solve for matching only one of those words, and I should be able to figure it out from there.  e.g. just solve for matching the first instance of 'port', but only when preceded by text like in the first two examples.  Keep in mind that the numbers can change and can be anywhere between 1-3 digits.

Comment: This was a good idea, but the problem is that this matches the numbers following 'card' as well.  I need just the words bolded in my question to be matched, exactly like it looks there.

Comment: card(?=[0-9]{1,2}_port) (positive lookahead) worked!  Thanks for trying to tackle this from different angles.  Though apparently I just tested to find 'port' using that style, and I found out that card(?=[0-9]{1,2}) works to find 'card' and port(?=[0-9]{1,2}) works to find 'port' in my examples.

Comment: Glad it helped!  The one issue with port(?=[0-9]{1,2}) would be if you had card an port out of order. ex: string_with_port32_or_card would still match port.  If you can be confident that this wont happen then that should be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

The `\b` assertion is not working in this case because `_` is considered a word character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wY1uY0/1)

You can use a look behind:

```
(?<=_)(card).*?(?<=_)(port)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ5zC5/1)

To be even more specific, use the IP address pattern:

```
(^(?:\d+_){4})(card\d+)_(port\d+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vJ5zC5/3)

Comment: I appreciate the response, but it wouldn't return any matches in http://regexpal.com/  I'm not sure why, but I can't load any pages from regex101.com

Comment: If you click the `m` flag in regexpal, these work in demo mode there too.

Comment: Your edited response matches everything from the beginning out to and including the port number.  Again, this is in regexpal.com since I can't load pages from regex101.com.

Comment: It still didn't work with the m flag checked in regexpal.  Both results remain the same.

Comment: `regexpal` is blinding you to what is being captured. The entire match is being shown highlighted but that is not what is being captured. Try `substring(line_of_your_text from '\d+_(card\d+)') if I recall Postgress...

Comment: And you can use `regexp_matches` for multiple capture groups

Comment: Your first pattern had an error (quantifier operand invalid in postgres), and the second just matches everything from the beginning out to the number of the port.

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this in two steps.  In the first, I matched only lines with the IP string in the beginning (this excludes lines like my 3rd example).  In the second step, I used regexp_replace to replace the first match of each word.

Unfortunately, I had completely missed the fact that regexp_replace only replaces the first match unless told otherwise with the 'g' flag:

```
WHEN (SELECT regexp_matches(mystring, '^1(?:[0-9]{1,3}_){4}card[0-9]{1,2}_port[0-9]{1,2}')) IS NOT NULL
  THEN regexp_replace(regexp_replace(mystring, 'card', 'c'), 'port', 'p')
```

Though I still wish I could figure out how to match one of those words in a single expression, and I would accept any answer that could achieve that.